# PHP Code to add two numbers , adding happens as soon as i type the second number in the second field with the result populating in the third field

Tags: php

PHP Code to add two numbers , adding happens as soon as i type the second number in the second field with the result populating in the third field.

Can it be done using php or we do use Ajax or other programming languages.

Would be helpful if i could get an answer for this.

Comment: use `javascript` to make changes immediately

Comment: not Possible without Ajax

Comment: Actually with pure JavaScript you can achieve that, bypassing any need for PHP or Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is enough for this purpose

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Adder()
{
var a= parseInt(document.frm.A.value);
var b = parseInt(document.frm.B.value);
var result=a+b;
document.frm.Result.value=result;
}
</script>
<form name="frm">
<input id="A" name="A" type="Text" onchange="Adder()" >
<input id="B" name="B" type="Text" onchange="Adder()" >
<input id="Result" name="Result" type="Text" >
</form>
```

Comment: Script will not work if parseInt will return NaN. E.g. when I type "He was 40"

Comment: validation was not my concern here, let the man do some code by himself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
$('#field2').change(function (){
   if(!isNaN($('#field1').val()) && !isNaN($('#field2').val()))
   {
         $('#field3').val($('#field1').val()+$('#field2').val())
   }
});
```

Where field1,field2, and field3 are the id of fields. It will put the addition in field3 only if the values entered in field 1 and field2 are numeric.

Comment: No validation and input checking. User can easily type some text data and script will stop working as expected.

Comment: @Carlos : I have changed my answer. Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript.

```
Script :

function add(){
var num1  = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var num2  = document.getElementById("num2").value;

sum       = num1+num2;
document.getElementById("sum").value = sum;
}


HTML:

<input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" />
<input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" onchange="add();" />
<input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" />
```

NOTE : this code is not tested please make relevant changes

Comment: what you want to tell in answer section?

Comment: `this code is not tested` what do you mean this? Means again the OP open a new thread?